# In how many ways can $n$ identical balls be distributed into $r$ urns so that $i$-th urn

Tags: combinatorics

> In how many ways can $n$ identical balls be distributed into $r$ urns so
> that $i$th urn contains at least $m_i$ balls for each $i=1,\dots,r$ ?
> Assume $n \geq \sum_{i=1}^r m_i $.

## Try

First, notice that if $x_i$ is the number of balls in urn $i$, then we are trying to find number of vectors $(x_1,\dots,x_n)$ that satisfy

$$ x_1 + \dots +x_r = n $$

so that $x_i \geq m_i$. IF we call $y_i = x_i - m_i$. Then, we can restate our problem as that to find vectors $(y_1,...,y_n)$ that satisfy

$$ y_1 + \dots + y_r = n - \sum_i^r m_i $$

and $y_i \geq 0$ and we know that there are ${n - \sum_i^r m_i + r - 1 \choose r-1}$ such solutions. Is this correct?

Comment: Looks good to me.

Comment: It's correct for full explanation you can check at https://www.mathsdiscussion.com/distribution-of-identical-objects-into-distinct-groups/  and also listen to podcast in that still if have any questions let forum know.